# my reason to call him dishonest Is it wrong?

Tags: usage

Are the following sentences correct?

1. My reason to call him dishonest...
2. The reason for me to call him dishonest...
3. I have a reason to call him dishonest...
4. I have reasons to call him dishonest...
5. I do not think I have any reason to call him dishonest.

If not, what is the correct way to say them?

Comment: The idiomatically natural phrasing is *My reason **for calling** him dishonest [**is** some reason]*. The infinitive syntax *(**to call**)* is an acceptable alternative to ***for calling*** in your example #5, but it's not idiomatic for any of the others. Also note that *in practice*, most native speakers wouldn't use "to call" here anyway - we'd usually express it as *My reason **for saying he is** dishonest [**is** some reason].*

Comment: Thanks a lot, and while I thinkof it, Is it idiomatic to say:"I have reason to say he is dishonest or I have no reason to say he is dishonest."?  ,

Comment: Both your "have reason" examples are syntactically fine. But *in practice* it's a fairly "dated" construction, AND the "set phrase" version is *to have reason to **believe** [something that seems credible]*. See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+reason+to+say%2CI+have+reason+to+believe&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20reason%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20reason%20to%20believe%3B%2Cc0) showing how far the usage has declined over the years.

Comment: (Probably the most likely context today where you'll encounter this construction today  is from an officer of the law saying something like *I have reason to believe [you have broken the law]*, as they smash down your front door in the middle of the night! :)